# Xamarin - Save bitmap image into resource

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I stack on the line bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
and I do not know how to continue. The following is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = tv.GetDrawingCache(true);
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
Java.IO.File ExternalStorageDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "Receipt");
Java.IO.FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
file.CreateNewFile();
fileOutputStream = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(file);
fileOutputStream.Write(stream.ToArray());
```

Comment: Well what is the problem? Should we guess? Put all info in your post.

Comment: But why use an intermediate stream? `bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);` ?? Replace by `bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, fileOutputStream);`. When done close the fileOutputStream.

Comment: `Xamarin - Save bitmap image into resource`. Wrong subject. One cannot save to resources. You are saving a bitmap to a png file.

Comment: the app bundle is not writable

Comment: ??? What are you trying to tell us?

Comment: Have you solved  your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Xamarin - Save bitmap image into resource

Here is a simple demo:

```
void ExportBitmapAsPNG(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.png");
    var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```